# Unwanted Spaces when concatenating fields and text strings

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I'm putting the following in my SQL select statement to concatenate text strings (which are not fields in the database) with a couple database fields and I'm getting spaces where I try to use the `to_char` function to add leading zeros to a couple fields.

Running:

```
SELECT 'EP.'||TO_CHAR(PWROTPR_TRANSX_NBR,'0000000')||'.'||TO_CHAR(PWROTPR_SUBMIT_COUNTER,'00') as ATS_NBR
```

Yields:
EP. 0017092. 01

How to I eliminate the unnecessary spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using replace function:

```
SELECT replace(('EP.'||TO_CHAR(PWROTPR_TRANSX_NBR,'0000000')||'.'||TO_CHAR(PWROTPR_SUBMIT_COUNTER,'00')), ' ', '') as ATS_NBR
```